# Ubuntu can't access the internet

Tags: windows, internet, windows-xp, virtualbox-networking

I just installed Ubuntu on my PC and I tried installing my 3G modem USB stick but that didn't work. After days of unending trials and Google searches, I finally found out I could run a Virtual Machine on my Ubuntu OS.

I got the VMWare virtual machine installed with Windows XP and tried my modem, it worked... I was thinking if there is a way to connect my host "Ubuntu" to access the internet directly from my virtual machine guest Windows XP.

Please I sincerely need the steps to do this.

Thanks in advance for your answers. :)

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:e263 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c045 Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: What modem model?

Comment: I guess its a Huawei 3G USB Modem, don't know the specific model, but I would like to just connect my host to VMware guest os "windowsxp"

Comment: Please post the output of `lsusb`

Comment: Please, append also the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*; ls -l /dev/ttyACM*`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to access the internet from Ubuntu while using the Windows XP guest OS as your interface to the 3G card?

If so, then you can try this:

1) In VirtualBox, configure a host only ethernet adaptor for Windows XP

2) Turn on ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) in Windows XP, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306126 for info.

3) Set up Ubuntu with the IP settings shown at the URL above.

4) If this indeed works, please let me know, because I don't test out any of my answers like this, and would like to know for future reference.